# Variational Principle for an Elliptic equation

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I wish to find the functional whose minimisation yields the follwoing equation on the vector function u
$(\lambda + \mu) \nabla (\nabla \cdot u) + \mu \nabla^{2} u = 0$,
the Navier equation of linear elasticity.
I know that this equation has a vaiational principle from physical reasons, but struggle to find it. The term containing the laplacian is easier to handle, I can not even prove simmetry of the weak form for the first one: how to integrate by parts (grad div u) v to obtain a term symmetric in u e v?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

By a [corollary of the divergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem#Corollaries):
$$\int_\Omega \nabla(\nabla\cdot u)\cdot v = - \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot u\,\nabla\cdot v + \int_{\partial\Omega}(\nabla\cdot g)v\cdot n.$$

Comment: That is right indeed! Thank you very much

Comment: Well, if you think that answer is correct, then marking it so helps this site (such that this question will not appear as unanswered anymore)…

Comment: Where did the $g$ come from?

Comment: It's from a boundary condition (not present in the question, but in the general form of the theorem).